# Python - Selenium returning empty results w/ all methods

Tags: python, django, selenium

This has been asked before but none seems to solve my issue.

I try to locate an element in [this page](https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/2003/Aston+Martin/DB7), but fail at my attempts:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(0, 0)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
url = "https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/2003/Aston+Martin/DB7"
driver.get(url)
print (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-qaid='txt-lowest-price']").text)
driver.close()
```

I can not scrape any other data from this page either (*by_id, by_name, by_class_name, by_css_selector*), all returning empty texts.

Any suggestion or feedback will be welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-qaid='txt-lowest-price']").text
```

with:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-qaid='txt-lowest-price']").get_attribute('textContent')
```